# Как и где лучше выполнять преобразование даты в UTC перед сохранением в базу и преобразовывать ее обратно в зону пользователя

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучший способ конвертации LocalDate в UTC перед сохранением её в базу данных MySQL через MyBatis.

Интересует место где лучше выполнять конвертацию в UTC и обратно в часовой пояс пользователя. Я думал выполнять это в TypeHandler, но там я не смогу получить его часового пояса.

Answer (score 0):

Конвертировать не нужно. Для MyBatis есть [Type Handlers for JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://github.com/mybatis/typehandlers-jsr310)
Затем используете как-то так:

```
<select id="getFoo" resultType="java.time.LocalDate">
        SELECT date from footable
</select>
```